# Error: 'int' object not iterable?

Tags: python

I have searched for a fix to my getting this error to no avail.  This is mostly because I don't iterate over anything in my code, except maybe the count variable, unless there is an implicit iteration in a library function I call.  Why am I getting this error?

```
import random
import math
rand = random.randint
floor = math.floor
count = 0
pastGuesses = None
ans = 0
success = False
low = 1
high = 100
player = ""

def initC():
    "Initialize the game mode where the user guesses."
    print "I will come up with a number between 1 and 100 and you have to guess it!"
    answer = rand(1, 100)
    player = "You"
    return answer
def guessEvalC(answer, g):
    "Pass the real answer and the guess, prints high or low and returns true if guess was correct."
    if g == answer:
        print "Correct!"
        return True, 1, 100
    elif g > answer:
        print "Too high!"
        return False, 1, 100
    else:
        print "Too low!"
        return False, 1, 100
def guessC(a, b):
    "Prompt user for a guess."
    suc = 0
    print "%u)Please enter a number." % (count)
    while True:
        try:
            gu = int(raw_input())
            if gu <= 100 and gu >= 1:
                return gu
            print "Outside of range, please try again."
        except ValueError:
            print "NAN, please try again."
def initU():
    "Initialize the game mode where the computer guesses."
    print "Think of a number between 1 and 100, and I'll guess it!"
    player = "I"
    return 0
def guessEvalU(a, b):
    "Prompt user for correctness of guess"
    print "Is this high, low, or correct?"
    s = raw_input()
    value = s[0]
    if value == "l" or value == "L":
        return False, b, high
    elif value == "h" or value == "H":
        return False, low, b
    else:
        return True
def guessU(l, h):
    "Calculations for guess by computer."
    guess = int(floor((l + h)/2))
    print "I guess %u!" % (guess)
    return guess
print "Guessing game!\nDo you want to guess my number?"
resp = raw_input("Yes or no. ")
mode = resp[0]
if mode == "y" or mode == "Y":
    init = initC
    guess = guessC
    guessEval = guessEvalC
else:
    init = initU
    guess = guessU
    guessEval = guessEvalU
ans = init()
while success != True:
    count = count + 1
    gue, low, high = guess(low, high)
    success = guessEval(ans, gue)
print "%s guessed it in %u tries!" % (player, count)
raw_input()
```

I get the error at line 77, is it because you can't mix types in a tuple?

```
gue, low, high = guess(low, high)
```

Edit: I had switched a couple of the function calls when I wrote this, `guessEval()` is the function that was supposed to return 3 items, while guess only returns 1.  The reason I was getting the `'int' object not iterable` error was that when you try to assign return values to a tuple of variables, the interpreter assumes that the object being returned by the function will be an iterable object.  `guess()` only returns one value, of type int, and when the interpreter tries to iterate through the returned object and place its contents into the desired variables, it returns this error.  It would be helpful if compilers/interpreters, when they return errors pertaining to a certain object, would mention what object the error message is referring to.  For instance `'int'(returned from guess()) object not iterable`.  Not really necessary as a feature, but it would be very useful.

Comment: If you search for this error, you will find 16k hits on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=int+object+not+iterable

Comment: I'm assuming that in the error message it gave you a line number.  Can you shorten this code to only include what was near the line number in the error message?

Comment: There's too much code here for it to be easy for someone else to spot your issue. Try reducing the code --- that is, cut out as much as you can so that all that's left is the smallest program you can make that still exhibits the same error. That way it's much easier for others (or you!) to spot the problem.

Comment: Hint : guess is a local variable. You need to call something else

Comment: Also, instead of `if mode == 'y' or mode == 'Y':`, use `if mode.lower() == 'y':`.  AND, instead of `import math; floor = math.floor` you should use `from math import floor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `guessC`:

```
gu = int(raw_input())
return gu
```

In the main loop:

```
gue, low, high = guess(low, high)
```

So, you are trying to receive three answers from a function that only returns one.

Either return an iterable from `guessC()` or assign to a single `int` in the main loop.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did.  Sometimes it just takes another critical eye to realize that you added the extra variable assignments to the call of the wrong function: guessEval is the function that returns 3 values.

Answer (score 1):

Both guessC and guessU returns just one value, but on line 77 you try to unpack 3 values.

The call to `guess` - waiting for the function to return 3 values:

```
gue, low, high = guess(low, high)
```

The functions return statement:

```
return gu
```

and:

```
return guess
```